# Is there a way on Google Maps (online version) to make Public transportation the default mode?

Tags: google-maps

Google Maps on Android allows the user to set his prefered mode of transportation. I didn't find a similar mode on the web-version. Does such a mode exist?

Comment: Curious, I'm sure you used to be able to do this. Since I used to have it always default to "walking" directions. But not anymore. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, there is no method of doing that. You could however go to Google Maps, select your preferred transit mode, and bookmark this link.

Comment: Good thing that the OP isn't reacting at all.....